# Rails – select current menu item

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have made a small helper that adds `class="selected"`. Primarily it uses `current_page?` to investigate if the present path is the current menu item, and the select it.

```
module MenuHelper
  #renders menu items and emphasizes current menu item
  def topmenu
    pages = {
      "products" => admin_products_path,
      "categories" => admin_categories_path,
      "catalogs" => admin_catalogs_path,
      "sales channels" => admin_sales_channels_path
    }
    pages.map do |key, value|
      classnames = %( class="current") if current_page?(value)
      "<li#{classnames}>#{link_to(key, value)}</li>"
    end
  end
end
```

And in /layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
<%= topmenu %>
</ul>
```

There is a big flaw in my approach. Selecting `/admin/catalogs` works like a charm. But any subpages do not (`/admin/catalogs/1`, etc.)

I think that my approach may be flawed by the limitations of the [`current_page?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001603) method

do you have any ideas on how I should either enhance this script to accept similar urls, or is there a smarter way to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I built a similar menu helper was to look at the `controller_name` and `action_name` attributes and then decide if a given page is selected/active or not. That's less specific than the full URL, so might be useful.

```
search_page_active = controller.controller_name == 'students' && \
                     controller.action_name == 'search'
```

Comment: This approach works fine, thanks! I made a slight change in my method and now it works. I had to replace `if current_page?(value)` with: `if controller.controller_name == key`

Answer (score 5):

A simple way for links :

```
def current_link_to label, path
  link_to label, path, class: (current_page?(path) ? "active" : nil)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have a lot of name spaced controllers, that is why I like to show if the current view also is in the Menu Path, I had use the solution of Michael van Rooijen and then I customize for my case.

#### Helper

```
def cp(path)
  "current" if request.url.include?(path)
end
```

#### View

```
<%= link_to "All Posts", posts_path, class: cp(posts_path) %>
```

Now if my menu bar is /users and my current page is /users/10/post also the link /users is set with "current" class

Comment: Great approach. I'd change `include?` to `start_with?` to avoid possible conflicts with identical URL parts, and use `request.path`, not `request.url` for consistency.

Comment: @D-side, your suggestions are great

Answer (score 0):

You could use `link_to_unless_current`.

Comment: I decided not to use `link_to_unless_current` because it's a different functionality. I *do* want a link to the menu item `catalogs_path` especially when looking on a sub page like catalog_path(@current_catalog).

Also, it's using the same method: `current_page?`. So it does not really help me